# Is GZIP compression output stable?

Tags: c, linux, gzip

I need to store remotely some chunks of data and compare them too see if there are duplications.
I will compile a specific C program and I would like to compress this chuncks with GZIP.

My doubt is: if I compress the same chunk of data with the same C program using a gzip library on different computers, will it give the exact same result or could it give different compressed results?

Target PC/Servers could be with different Linux OSs like Ubuntu/CentOs/Debian, etc.

May I force same result by statically linking a specific gzip library?

Comment: Why don't you use a digest like SHA256? It's faster, simpler, there is even less data to transfer, and it is 100% stable.

Comment: *"if I compress the same chunck of data with the same C program using gzip library in different computer will it give the exact same result*" - well, I am sure it *can* give different results depending on the compression level used by default and and the coding used... e.g. GNU gzip uses LZ77 and OpenBSD gzip uses compress... so I would really avoid relying on it and use an hash function as @Jabberwocky suggests instead.

Comment: @fpmurphy you can easily do `zcat data | sha256sum` though, which is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: Another probably simpler way would be storing both the hash of the original data and the gzipped data on the server. When you want to store the data remotely send the hash to the server first, and then gzip and send the new data if the server says the hash doesn't match.

Comment: @fpmurphy The idea is following: 1. tell the remote server to compute the digest of the remote data and send it to you. 2. compute the digest of the local data. 3. compare the two digests: If they are different/equal the remote and the local data is most likely different/equal as well.

Comment: @fpmurphy and I am not talking about verifying the integrity of the data either. What me and Jabberwocky are suggesting is to simply use hashes to check for duplicates instead of comparing binary blobs of compressed data which could give false negatives/positives.

Answer (score 2):

> if I compress the same chunk of data with the same C program using a gzip library on different computers, will it give the exact same result or could it give different compressed results?

While it may be true in the majority of the cases, I don't think you can safely make this assumption. The compressed output can differ depending on the default compression level and coding used by the library. For example the GNU `gzip` tool uses LZ77 and OpenBSD `gzip` uses compress ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#Implementations)). I don't know if this difference comes from different libraries or different configurations of the same library, but nonetheless I would really avoid assuming that a generic chunk of gzipped data is exactly the same when compressed using different implementations.

> May I force same result by statically linking a specific gzip library?

Yes, this could be a solution. Using the same version of the same library with the same configuration across different systems would give you the same compressed output.

---

You could also avoid this problem in other ways:

1. Perform the compression on the server, and only send uncompressed data (this is probably not a good solution as sending uncompressed data is slow).
2. Use hashes of the uncompressed data, store them on the server and check them by making the client send an hash first, and then the compressed data in case the server says the hash doesn't match (i.e. the chunk is not a duplicate). This also has the advantage of only needing to check the hash (and avoiding compression altogether if the hash matches).
3. Similar to option 2, use hashes of the uncompressed data, but always send compressed data to the server. The server then does decompression (which can be easily done in memory using a relatively small buffer) and hashes the uncompressed data to check if the received chunk is a duplicate before storing it.

Comment: I planned to upload millions of chuncks so I wonder about possible collision of different chuncks with same hash. The chuncks will be gzipped and krypted before upload, server should not have the key to decrypt them, but should mantain and share the hash of gzipped+krypted chunck for corruption check over time, so it would be nice to compare this already available info to check if the chuncks are duplicated.

Comment: @GiovanniOrlandi do you really care that much about collision? Take into consideration that a collision for SHA256 [is yet to be found](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet). Based on what you say approach number 2 seems fine, but yeah, there is always an infinitesimal probability of collision. In case you want to avoid any possibility of collision then your proposed solution is the only one which makes sense to me (statically link the same version of the same gzip lib into your code on every platform and use the same configuration).

Comment: @GiovanniOrlandi also keep in mind that in this case (using the same static lib) you will need to either 1) never update it or 2) make sure that updates of the lib don't change the underlying algorithm or config, which could lead to different results when using a new version of your software.

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless you are 100% certain you are using exactly the same version of the same source code with the same settings, and that you have disabled the modified timestamp in the gzip header.

It's not clear what you're doing with these compressed chunks, but if the idea is to have less to transmit and compare, then you can do *far* better with a hash. Use a SHA-256 on your uncompressed chunks, and then you can transmit and compare those in no time. The probability of an accidental match is so infinitesimally small, you'd have to wait for all the stars to go out to see one such occurrence.

Comment: It's a curious case. OP's question is unclear what he's doing but this topic comes up in reproducible builds. https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds/TimestampsInGzipHeaders

Answer (score 0):

> May I force same result by statically linking a specific gzip library?

That's not enough, you also need the same compression level at the very least, as well as any other options your particular properties your library might have (usually it's just the level).

If you use the same version of the library *and* the same compression level, then it's *likely* that the output is identical (or stable, as you call it). That's not a very strong guarantee however, I'd recommend using a hashing function instead, that's what they're meant for.